# defining default time zone

Tags: php, date, symfony

i just started to php using symfony framework. At first i did not get any error about date_default_timezone_get() but later on i get an error like

> date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's
>   timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting
>   or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of
>   those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in
>   C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\SymfonyRequirements.php on line 441

i changed my php.ini to

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Europe/Istanbul
```

but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default timezone by overriding the **AppKernel** function.

```
<?php
// AppKernel.php

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    //..
    //.......
    //...........
    // --- Append the init function below ---

    public function init()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set( 'Asia/Kolkata' );
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

**Note:** init method was [deprecated](https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/commit/9141877ff6d64a422e249510a84940be3ff6f35f#diff-1) since version 2.3, to be removed in 3.0. You must move your logic in the constructor instead:

```
public function __construct($environment, $debug)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
}
```

[See detail description](http://dploy.in/2012/setting-the-default-timezone-symfony2/)

Comment: i changed the AppKernel.php located in "www/Symfony/app" folder but still same error.

Answer (score 1):

Well ... you got the answer in the error. Add this in the beginning of your script:

```
date_default_timezone_set("your_timezone");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

List of all timezones is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: do i have to write it to all of my pages?

Comment: Well, yes. I usually use one page (its called common.php most of the time) and include it in every other .php file. In this common.php, i define everything which is important, like templatesettings, databaseconnections or initialization of variables, getting the latest time and so on. If you dont do so, you have to add it in every page, yes.

Comment: Actually you don't have to. That is what php.ini is for.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the necessary line in php.ini (date.timezone) then resetting your server should solve your problem. You changed the line but probably didn't reset your server.